# Scope error with update() and glm()

Tags: r, function, scope

I think I incurred in a oddity of `R`.

I'm building a function `do.regression()` to manage many type of regressions.

In the case of logistic regression, my function calls out `glm2(x, data=model.data, family = family.fun, ...)`. The family function for glm() can is an argument of my function, via the family.fun argument. The default is `family.fun = binomial`.

Inside my function I have a call to another custom function `logLikRatio.test <- function (model, model.ref = F )` which calculate the log likelihood ratio. Inside this new function I make a call to `update()` to generate a null model, eg. `update(model, . ~ 1)`.

Here I get an error:

```
   Error in glm2(formula = y ~ 1, family = family.fun, data = model.data) : 
   object 'family.fun' not found
```

somehow `R`expect to find family.fun inside `logLikRatio.test()`. 
To test my hypothesis I defined `family.fun <- binomial`inside it. But I have the error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'model.data' not found
```

The same for the argument model.data... `R` won't traverse the function tree enough to find these variables.

UPDATE:
I stripped down my functions to isolate the problematic parts:

```
fake.do.regression <- function(x, data = globalenv(), family.fun = binomial) {
    model.data <- model.frame(x, data)
    model <- glm2(x, data=model.data, family = family.fun)
    fake.logLikRatio.test(model)
}

fake.logLikRatio.test <- function (model, model.ref = F ) {
    if (model.ref == F) {

        #family.fun <- binomial

        model.ref <- update(model, . ~ 1, F)
    }
    return( anova(model, model.ref, test="LRT")[2, 'Pr(>Chi)'])
}
```

Calling fake.do.regression(y ~ x) reproduce the first error; if the `#family.fun <- binomial` is uncommented, you get the second error.

Comment: this is an interesting problem, and not surprising to me (`update` gets tricky).  Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi Ben! looks like you're following my craziness with R from site to site! :D
It's tricky to recreate it... I'll try

Comment: easier than I thought...

Comment: To be honest I don't understand scoping enough to explain it, but it works for me if I change the update call to `update(model, . ~ 1, evaluate = FALSE)`, with and without the `family.fun` bit.